# Unresolved error in AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, xml, error-handling, android-manifest

This is my xml code:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.init.Game99"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.init.Game99_AndroidLibrary.NNGame"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:label="Game99-AndroidLibrary"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

I am getting these two errors and I have no idea how to fix it. I have tried googling and from what i understand, application is a direct child of manifest and so on. I'm not entirely sure what it is i am doing wrong.

These are the errors I am getting:

[image: errors]

Comment: It looks like the first line of your manifest file is missing (at least, based on what's displayed in your question)? It should say something like `<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` (and don't forget the close tag at the bottom of the file). Compare what you have with the [example here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html). The errors are probably a direct result of the currently malformed xml file.

Comment: Yes.. Two lines are missing in your manifest. `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.corbone.beno.client.android"></manifest>`

Comment: Hi, sorry about that, i have edited my code to include the first line, which i didn't copy the first time round.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should look something like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.init.Game99"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.init.Game99_AndroidLibrary.NNGame"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:label="Game99-AndroidLibrary"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Check whether you are enclosing the tags properly.

Comment: Thank you! Do you mind explaining what it is you have done differently?

Comment: I added
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
on the top of my file and it worked! thank you so much!

Comment: Your code does not showed up <manifest/ > tag .And Errors were pointing towards the misplaced tags. As per documentation : In AndroidManifest.xml ,  <manifest> must contain an <application> element and specify xmlns:android and package attributes which were lacking in your code. SO I presented the code with them :) ! Hope its clear to you now.